# How to apply basis-n (flex-basis in tailwindcss) to an element itself?

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I would like to build a timezone reference (similar to the many that already exist) with a few columns showing the relevant times for selected cities.

In order for the columns to be the same size, I want to set the width of the city names to a set value (it will be calculated, for the sake of example I am using `basis-72` = 18rem = 288px).

```html
<div class="flex flex-row">
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0 basis-72">San Diego</div>
    <div class="text-center">15:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">16:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">13:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">14:00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0 basis-72">Paris</div>
    <div class="text-center">00:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">01:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">22:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">23:00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0 basis-72">Boston</div>
    <div class="text-center">18:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">19:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">16:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">17:00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The result can be seen (and played with) at [tailwindPLAY](https://play.tailwindcss.com/TOP4wkaSZo):

[image: result of the playground]

It seems that `basis-72` was applied on the height of the row, along the column axis. I wanted, however, to apply it to the name of the city (`San Diego` for instance).

My understanding is that `flex: 0 0 18rem;` would be applied **to the element** (i.e the content of the `div` with the text, and not to children.

If this is an incorrect understanding, how to apply it to the text in the `div`?

Comment: Since the flex layout is a vertical layout, `flex-basis` would indeed set the "base" height of the element. What is your desired behavior?

Comment: @Wongjn: to have `San Diego`, `Paris` and `Boston` in divs that would be 18rem (`basis-72`) wide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the flex layout is a vertical layout, `flex-basis` would set the "base" *height* of the element. To have the "San Diego", "Paris" and "Boston" in the `<div>` elements that would be `18rem` wide, you could consider applying `width: 18rem` via the `w-72` utility class:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="flex flex-row">
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0 w-72">San Diego</div>
    <div class="text-center">15:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">16:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">13:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">14:00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0 w-72">Paris</div>
    <div class="text-center">00:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">01:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">22:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">23:00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-col">
    <div class="flex flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0 w-72">Boston</div>
    <div class="text-center">18:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">19:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">16:00</div>
    <div class="text-center">17:00</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was under the impression that for flex elements, the style must be flex-based. If I use a simple `width`, why are `flex flex-shrink-0 flex-grow-0` still useful?

Comment: They aren't useful in this context.